# How do I get Highcharts' areaspline to look good with only one data point?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Attached are two screenshots of my graph. The chart looks fantastic with more than one point of data in the series. However, when there's only one point, "nothing" displays up unless you mouseover. This is because the chart has nothing to connect those points to, but of course this is not really desired.

I hacked it by padding the data set with a zero on the front and a zero on the back, but I really don't like this approach. Is there a highcharts setting somewhere that will allow the chart to connect to the leftmost side and the rightmost side and show a sort-of "hump" in the middle?

[image: regular chart with multiple data points]

[image: one data point, mouseover]

Comment: No, there is no such setting. Of course, if you only have one data point, it really doesn't make any sense to display it that way either. You can do a check on your data, and if you only have one data point, make sure markers are enabled (setting them all to a circle marker symbol will take away some of the oddity in your example).

Comment: yeah, that's what i was starting to consider, but it's just inconsistent with the rest of the design. rock > this feature < hard place!

Comment: Then only option is to use fake point, when you have only one point. For example `if (data.length == 1) { data.push(data[0]); }` before rendering a chart. But there will be problem with x-axis labels - what those should display? I guess duplicated date should be fine?